# Code smell Id = blah== null ? null : something.x ? null : something.y

Tags: c#

Any tips on how to fix this code smell (not my code):

```
Id = blah== null ? null : something.x ? null : something.y
```

Is perlish writing considered beneficial in C#? is using multiple lines and being clear a bad thing? How the hell is anyone to read the above? it is has takes 2 "if"s to assign a value.

Is there cleaner way of dealing with above?

Comment: It's called a `ternary` operator. You can unpack that to `if` statements. But basically that is what the code does.

Comment: @zaitsman : yes, I know about ternary if operator as I had originally wrote in my post, the question is how is one to understand it in one line?

Comment: by practicing? kind of the same way that if you want to learn a foreign language, you just practice it.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen or devrant. jimjim: well for one: it's much harder to smuggle in method calls with unexpected side effects. but your question was about "how to understand them", wasn't it? then the answer is: calm down and learn ternary.

Comment: @jimjim who considered nesting ifs `bad`? why is it `bad`?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen : Thank you, your usage of IF made me smile, I'll answer my own question as it looks like no one is getting what I am getting at.

Comment: `Id = (blah == null || something.x) ? null : something.y` might be slightly simpler in this specific case.

Comment: @mjwills : thank you, that actually helps to unravel what was going through them mind of the person who wrote it and why the wrote it that way.

Comment: @jimjim If two branches return the same value (as in here) then usually one of the ternaries can be removed reasonably safely.

Comment: @zaitsman : apologies, nesting if's is really good for some, maybe I had to much faith in structured programming.

Comment: This example is kind of the lower end of readable and sane code.. Additionally there is a special place in hell for people who would use the name `x` as a `bool`... I would fail this code review commit just on principle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, another alternative to consider would be:

```
Id = (blah == null || something.x) ? null : something.y;
```

The benefit being that only one ternary is necessary (and thus `null` is returned from only one "branch" out of two, rather than two out of three).

Answer (score 3):

This is [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), For clear understanding you can convert it into `if..else` condition

Like,

```
if(blah == null)
{
   Id = null;
}
else
{
   if(something.x)
      Id = null;
   else
      Id = something.y;
}
```

In your case ternary operator is used twice, so it might look confusing. Syntax of ternary operator is

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems hard to read, but you could put each condition and statements in a line, it could be more easy to read.

```
Id = blah== null  //Condition
? null            //Then
: something.x     //Condition
? null            //Then
: something.y     //Else
```

Comment: If you like this approach, indentation might help to work out what the `:` applies to (i.e. indent the last two lines).

Comment: Yes, this is on the way of helping, as @mjwills mentioned having the last two lines independent helps reading the code